# How can I get the CMYK values from a REAL printed image?

Tags: color, print-design, cmyk

I've been designing web graphics for a long time, but I've been requested to print out some new work. The client presented me a **printed magazine page** and asked me to make her logo the exact same color as the one on the page. Is there a way I can get the values (not the color) on my computer so I can then print it out and get it to look like the magazine color? I'm talking about some tool, formula, magic trick!!

I know I should be better at working my colors, but I'm not quite! Any help/advice will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The magic trick is your eyes. Find a Pantone cmyk swatch book (or take it to your printer...they should have one) and find the swatch that matches.

FYI, a client should KNOW what specific color their logo is. If they don't, it likely wasn't professionally designed to begin with. Might be an opportunity to pitch them a logo refresh project.

Answer (score 0):

Scan the document with a high quality setting. You will have to experiment with the setting. And then find the exact pantone which can be well related to the document scanned.

Comment: The issue with this solution is the scanner often does a color conversion too. The scanned image cannot be entirely trusted because of this.

Comment: That's the reason you need to experiment with the setting. It's a one time thing.

Comment: Maybe you could add details to your answer then. For example, how to experiment with the setting as you mentioned, how to know when the "setting" is right and then how to find the Pantone based on the scanned image you got.

Comment: scanner needs to be calibrated, but then if you have a colorimeter you can use that on your data.